# Align decimal numbers in part of the table that has parentheses

Tags: tables, siunitx, dcolumn, decimal-number

I want to create the following table, and I have several questions as follows:

In the table, I want to align decimal numbers above the "Observations," including the numbers in the parentheses and with `***`. At the same time, I want that the R^2 and Observations are in the center (not align with decimal numbers). Is there any effective way to achieve this？

```
\begin{table}[h] \centering
\sisetup{input-symbols = {( )}}
\captionsetup{font=tenpt}
   \caption{Example table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{5}{S[table-format = +5.5]}@{}}
\toprule
Groups & {15-30}  & {31-50} & {31-59}  & {50-15} & {$\geq$ 15} \\
\hline


Tea  & 0.10 & 0.50  & 0.10 & 0.60  & 0.60 \\
  & (511.32) & (966.51) & (363.02) & (61.60) & (15.11)  \\ 
Apple & 3,521.20^{***} & 2,560.61^{**} & 116.15 & 212.01^{***} & -53.20^{**} \\
  & (511.95) & (661.61) & (352.02) & (16.59) & (13.55)   \\ 
 \multirow{2}{2.2cm}{Tea \times Apple} & -1,936.55^{***} & -1,095.05 & -522.16  & 21.15 & -22.15 \\ 
   & (562.56) & (1,256.15)  & (563.16) & (91.61) & (19.15)  \\

\hline 
Observations & 566 & 566 & 566 & 566  & 566  \\

$R^{2}$ & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.03 & 0.05 &0.03  \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The following table is the version that I got in Overleaf with the warning "overfull \hbox (4.23pt too wide) detected at line xxx...":

[image: The results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, 
         input-open-uncertainty = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-align-text-pre = false,
         table-align-text-post = false,
         group-minimum-digits=4}
%\captionsetup{font=tenpt}
\caption{Example table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{5}{S[table-format = -4.2, table-space-text-post=$^{***}$]}@{}}
\toprule
Groups & {15--30}  & {31--50} & {31--59}  & {50--15} & {$\geq$ 15} \\
\midrule


Tea                & 0.10             & 0.50           & 0.10     & 0.60           & 0.60         \\
                   & (511.32)         & (966.51)       & (363.02) & (61.60)        & (15.11)      \\
\addlinespace 
Apple              & 3521.20$^{***}$  & 2560.61$^{**}$ & 116.15   & 212.01$^{***}$ & -53.20$^{**}$ \\
                   & (511.95)         & (661.61)       & (352.02) & (16.59)        & (13.55)       \\ 
\addlinespace 
Tea $\times$ Apple & -1936.55$^{***}$ & -1095.05       & -522.16  & 21.15          & -22.15        \\ 
                   & (562.56)         & (1256.15)      & (563.16) & (91.61)        & (19.15)       \\
\midrule 
Observations       & {566}            & {566}          & {566}    & {566}          & {566}         \\
$R^{2}$            & {0.01}           & {0.01}         & {0.03}   & {0.05}         & {0.03}        \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

The following code should work with the older version of `siunitx`, that is currently used by overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, 
         input-open-uncertainty = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-align-text-pre = false,
         table-align-text-post = false,
         group-minimum-digits=4, 
         table-space-text-pre ={(},
         table-space-text-post={$^{***}$}}
%\captionsetup{font=tenpt}
\caption{Example table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{5}{S[table-format = -4.2]}@{}}
\toprule
Groups & {15--30}  & {31--50} & {31--59}  & {50--15} & {$\geq$ 15} \\
\midrule


Tea                & 0.10             & 0.50           & 0.10     & 0.60           & 0.60         \\
                   & ( 511.32)         & (966.51)       & (363.02) & (61.60)        & (15.11)      \\
\addlinespace 
Apple              & 3521.20$^{***}$  & 2560.61$^{**}$ & 116.15   & 212.01$^{***}$ & -53.20$^{**}$ \\
                   & (511.95)         & (661.61)       & (352.02) & (16.59)        & (13.55)       \\ 
\addlinespace 
Tea $\times$       & -1936.55$^{***}$ & -1095.05       & -522.16  & 21.15          & -22.15        \\ 
Apple              & (562.56)         & (1256.15)      & (563.16) & (91.61)        & (19.15)       \\
\midrule 
Observations       & {566}            & {566}          & {566}    & {566}          & {566}         \\
$R^{2}$            & {0.01}           & {0.01}         & {0.03}   & {0.05}         & {0.03}        \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now there is the full compilable code :-)

Comment: 1- In my Overleaf version,  an error occurred "overfull \hbox (4.23pt too wide) detected at line xxx..." Then, the numbers are wider than the parentheses in the table. 2- I want to still use ```\multirow{2}{2.2cm}{Tea \times Apple}``` to break tea and apple in two different lines (since I have long words for other tables), but it returns an error "missing $ inserted". How to fix these two issues?

Comment: @leandriis, Many thanks! I re-edited my questions, could you please help address them?

Comment: @Lernst: I just updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @leandriis, Many thanks. Actually, I have manually used the new Siunitx package, and both codes work. Could you please help explain why you use ```table-format = -4.4``` and ```group-minimum-digits=4```? Do you have any suggested source to learn this?

Comment: @Lernst: There was a small mistake in my first exmple code that I just fixed. Please have a look at the updated version of the code. `table-format` informs `siunitx` what kind of numbers are inside of the table column. I used `-4.2` here, since you have negative numbers with a maximum of 4 digits left of the decimal separator and a maximum of 2 digits right of the decimal separator. `group-minimum-digits=4` makes sure, that group (thousand) separators are also used in numbers with 4 digits left of the decimal separator. (By default, they are only used in numbers with 5 digits.)

Comment: `table-space-text-post=$^{***}$` makes sure there is enough space for the asterisks right of the numbers. You probably also noticed, that I removed the explicit group separators (comma) in the numbers in your table. This was due to a bug in `siunitx`, that is fixed in version v3.0.22. So if you prefer to input your numbers like `3,521.20` as opposed to `3521.20`, use this newer version of `siunitx`.